# How to add characters in word and replace it using sed command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have one requirement.

I have one text file named as a.txt, which is having list of words -

```
GOOGLE
FACEBBOK
```

Now I have one another file named as b.txt , which is having content as

```
Company name is google.
Company name is facebook.
```

Like this n of lines are there with different different words.

Then I am writing script file -

```
    FILENAME="a.txt"

SCHEMA=$(cat $FILENAME)

for L in $SCHEMA
do
    echo "${L,,}"

sed -i -E "s/.+/\L&_/" b.txt
done
```

So after running script the output file of b.txt file I am expecting is

```
 Company name is google_
 Company name is facebook_
```

But the output after running that script I am getting is -

```
Company name is google.__
Company name is facebook.__
```

And this output will be saved in b.txt file as I mentioned in sed command

Note - In **a.txt** I am having the list of Words which I want to replace and in **b.txt** file I am having paragraphs of line in which I am having words like **google.** , **facebook.** and so on.

So that's why I am not able to give direct sed command for replacement.

I hope that you understand my requirement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tangentially, [don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following GNU `sed` solution:

```
FILENAME="a.txt"
while IFS= read -r L; do
  sed -i "s/\($L\)\./\1_/gI" b.txt
done < $FILENAME
```

Or, the same without a loop as a single line (as used in [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64153749/3832970)):

```
sed -i -f <(printf 's/\\(%s\\)\\./\\1_/gI\n' $(<"$FILENAME")) b.txt
```

With the script, you

- `while IFS= read -r L; do` - read the file line by line, each line being assigned to `L`
- `sed -i "s/\($L\)\./\1_/gI" b.txt` - replaces all occurrences of `L` (captured into Group 1 with the help of capturing `\(...\)` parentheses) followed with `.` (in a case insensitive way due to `I` flag) in `b.txt` with the same value as captured in Group 1 and `_` appended to it.
- `-f`  allows passing a list of commands to `sed`
- `printf 's/\\(%s\\)\\./\\1_/gI\n' $(<"$FILENAME")` creates a list of `sed` commands, in this case, it looks like

```
s/\(GOOGLE\)\./\1_/gI
s/\(FACEBOOK\)\./\1_/gI
```

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew for your reply. Actually after applying your script I am getting output as - google.__ and facebook.__ that is double "_" it is adding and its not eliminating "." also.  Can you help me with this?
Actually in a.txt I am having the list of words which I want to change in b.txt file. So applying for loop for every word.

Comment: @saurabh704 Why eliminate `.` if there is no `.` in your input? Or did you share wrong input? Did you use `sed -i -E "s/.+/\L&_/"` or `sed -i "s/.*/\L&_/"`? If you used the latter, try `sed -i "s/..*/\L&_/"`

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew for your time. I have edited the question please see if you are able to understand my requirement.

Comment: @saurabh704 See  my new answer. Yes, after the edit, the question is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it in a single shell command without any loop using `gnu-sed` with `printf` in a process substitution:

```
sed -i -E -f <(printf 's/\\b(%s)\\./\\1_/I\n' $(<a.txt)) b.txt

cat b.txt
```

```
Company name is google_
Company name is facebook_
```

This would be far more efficient than running `sed` or `awk` in a loop esp if input files are big in size.

- `printf` command is creating a `sed` command script that looks like this:

```
s/\b(GOOGLE)\./\1_/I
s/\b(FACEBOOK)\./\1_/I
```

- `sed -f` runs that dynamically generated script

Comment: Thank you @anubhava so much . Without using loop also it worked for me

Comment: @saurabh704, hey Saurabh, could you please check my solution too if that helped you?

Answer (score 1):

With a single `awk` reading 2 Input_files could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[tolower($0)]
  next
}
($(NF-1) in a){
  sub(/\.$/,"")
  print $0"_"
}
' a.txt FS="[ .]" b.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above solution.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                     ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when a.txt is being read.
  a[tolower($0)]             ##Creating array a with index of current line in lower case from a.txt here.
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($(NF-1) in a){              ##Checking condition if 2nd last field is present in array a then do following.
  sub(/\.$/,"")              ##Substituting last DOT with NULL here.
  print $0"_"                ##Printing current line with _ here.
}
' a.txt FS="[ .]" b.txt      ##Mentioning a.txt and setting field separator as space and . for b.txt here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding 1 more solution with `awk` here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[tolower($0)]
  next
}
{
  sub(/\.$/,"")
}
($NF in a){
  print $0"_"
}
' a.txt b.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#s/(&)./\\1_/Ig#' a.txt | sed -i -Ef - b.txt
```

N.B. The match is case insensitive because of the `I` flag on the substitution command, however the replacement is from the original file i.e. if the original string is `google` the match is case insensitive to `GOOGLE` and replaced by `google_`.